# JSF 2: duplicate IDs inside p:dataList

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, mojarra

i have a list of billable services per client and i'm trying to build a table where the user can select which ones shall actually be billed:

```
<p:dataList value="#{billController.billings}" var="billings">
    <p:dataTable value='#{billings.billablesDataModel}' var='item' selection="#{billings.toBill}">
        <f:facet name="header"> 
            <h:outputText value="#{billings.client.id}" />
        </f:facet>

        [...]

    </p:dataTable>
</p:dataList>
```

the problem is, that all the dataTables are rendered with the same ID attribute (`j_idt9:j_idt13:0:j_idt14`) which is automatically assigned by JSF. i'm suspecting this is causing that the selection doesn't work. (the backing bean `billings.toBill` is not updated/stays empty.)

i was trying to set the ID attribute of the `dataTable` manually like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="#{billings.client.id}" ...>
```

however, i get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty id attribute is not allowed
```

(`#{billings.client.id}` is definitely set to the unique client's ID as i get the right output from an `h:outputText` for debug purposes.)

can you help me fixing this?

i'm using JSF Mojarra 2.1.1 and PrimeFaces 3.2 on a Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use p:column for content of datalist as documented in user's guide.

Comment: This worked for me on a similar problem.  Adding the column to the DataList (not the DataTable used in the example, which I believe also needs a column) worked.  But it's not mentioned in the user guide anywhere in the DataList section as far as I can see.

Comment: excellent, this worked! i followed the datalist showcase examples where the p:column is missing. i also couldn't find it in the user's guide. anyways, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

What if you loop over `billController.billings` via `ui:repeat` and not via `p:dataList`:

```
<ui:repeat var="billings" value="#{billController.billings}">
    <p:dataTable value="#{billings.billablesDataModel}" var="item" selection="#{billings.toBill}">
        [...]
    </p:dataTable>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: ui:repeat delivers exactly the same result.